# Issue with callback in using firebase and node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to fetch the signedURL of an image in Cloud Storage and return it to the post method of the node.js server.

But the returned value always turns out to be undefined. Please refer the code.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
    var sign;
   var signedFinal = getUrl('cpu2.png',function(){
        console.log("hello" +signedFinal);
    });



function getUrl(image, callback){
        const file = bucket.file(image);
        const action = 'read';
        const expires = '03-09-2491';
        file.getSignedUrl({action:"read", expires}).then(function(url){
            sign=url[0];
            return url[0];
        }).catch(function (error) {
            {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With async function element/result has to be returned in callback :

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

```
function getUrl(image, callback){
        const file = bucket.file(image);
        const action = 'read';
        const expires = '03-09-2491';
        file.getSignedUrl({action:"read", expires}).then(function(url){
            sign=url[0];
            return callback(url[0]);

        }).catch(function (error) {

           return callback(null);

        });

}

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {

    getUrl('cpu2.png',function(signedFinal){
        console.log("hello" +signedFinal);

        // do something here
        return res.status(200).json({img: signedFinal});
    });

});
```